# Instantiate game object with added tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am instantiating my prefab into the scene and looking for an easy way to access it and change this object (size, Sprite renderer...).
Is there a way to give cloned objects for example tag or other way to change it direclty?

bird= Instantiate(birdPrefab).GetComponent();

Comment: When calling Instantiate, you are usually implicitly calling a generic overload that returns the new instance of the same type as the prefab. Can't you use that and edit its values?

Comment: Well bird now contains the reference to the gameobject. You can do with it as you require.

Comment: I am trying to instantiate the prefab and by clicking the other button change only instantiated object, not the whole prefab.
Sorry if I misunderstood your comment

Comment: You are already doing it in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the instantiated object in a variable like you do in your example.
But instead of bird = Instantiate(birdPrefab).GetComponent(); you could just do bird = Instantiate(birdPrefab) and later do a bird.GetComponent<>(); to change it's value.

Otherwise if you instantiate multiple gameobjects and you want to edit them all you could give the prefab a certain tag and with FindGameObjectsWithTag("Your Tag") you will get all gameobjects with that tag in a list.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't think about it.